# Clerk Auth - GET http://localhost:3000/ 401 (Unauthorized) - 401 Loop after Signin/Signout

Tags: next.js, http-status-code-401, app-router, clerk

Good day,

I have been trying to setup Clerk on Next lastest version with the app the App router.

I have went through the well written docs and it seem pretty straighforward to setup so I gave it a shot on a new project I have been working on.

I have followed the get started instructions provided by CLerk without sucess: https://clerk.com/docs/nextjs/get-started-with-nextjs

The issue I'm facing is that once authorized on signin or signup I get redirected to the route I have setup in my env.local as planned, but I start getting on infinite loop of GET http://localhost:3000/ 401 (Unauthorized) error.The only way to get out of that loop is to stop the Next server or delete the localstorage files stored by Clerk

I though that I made mistake in the intial setup but everytimes I go through the instructions I'm facing the same issue over and over again.

I have also tried to run the example provided by Clerk on Github clerkinc/clerk-next-app-router-starter and I get the same error. The only manual settings I performed is adding the API key and Secret in the .env.local file

-Followed the get started instructions provided by CLerk
-Try multiple browser (Firefox/Chrome)
-Run the clerkinc/clerk-next-app-router-starter repository example
-Create another Clerk applications 9user pool)

As mentionned above everythig seem to be setup according to the official docs

I was looking forward to leverage an auth product that do most of the heavy lifting. Anyone facing the same issue or would recommend a path to look into as I'm getting out of idea here?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I just had this issue myself and was able to fix it. Add the following key value to authMiddleware.

```
authMiddleware({ debug: true })
```

This will tell you what is causing the 401 and infinite loading for your app. For me, it was the reason was "token-not-active-yet", which was due to incorrect time set on my computer.

Comment: Thank you so much kind stranger! This is exactly what resolved the issue as my time was also incorrectly sync.

Comment: @YanickLarouche, I face the same issue, how did you resolve it?

Comment: I am facing the same issue but in production environment